# jquery 1.8 trigger

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I'm working on a project for a customer. The site uses jQuery 1.8.2. In a previous project (jQuery 1.9.1) I use:

```
$("select#testbuecher").trigger("add", [$item]);
```

for a custom event. This does not work with 1.8.2.

The error in Firebug:

> NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments

Anyone here who knows what's wrong with the code?

Comment: the jquery manual looks like it requires 2 arguments http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ `$('#foo').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event']);`

Comment: @DannyHearnah: The OP *is* passing 2 arguments.  `.trigger("add", [$item])`

Comment: How is the `add` event bound to the element?  We need to see some more code, this line is fine.

Comment: Also, have you made sure $item is actually defined?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - bound with "$('select#testbuecher').bind('add', function(a, b)"

Comment: @Boaz - Yes it is, work with 1.9.1

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution. Instead of using only "trigger", "triggerHandler" do the job.

```
$("select#testbuecher").triggerHandler("add", [$item]);
```